# Bash: Checking a string contains numbers within a certain range

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, mips

I'm writing a bash script to check the syntax of some simple MIPS instructions. One of the things I need it to do is to check that a valid register number has been given.

So let's say it reads the instruction...

```
add $s0, $s1, $s2
```

...it should check that the integer after the the s is within a given range. How would I implement that?

**If there's something easily Google-able to help me with this, please say. I thought there would be, but alas I wasn't able to find anything. :(*

Comment: Why don't you use the assembler to detect syntax errors?

Comment: Does your range go into double digits? Give a little more specifics...

Comment: @hek2mgl it's a University coursework project.

Comment: @PeterBowers Yep. I need to represent integers 0-31.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow $s0 to $s7 but not above then this would work:

```
grep -E '\$s([89]|\d\d)' myfile
```

If you want to go up to 23 but not beyond it gets a little more complicated:

```
grep -E '\$s(2[4-9]|[3-9]\d|\d\d\d)' myfile
```

For 31:

```
grep -E '\$s(3[2-9]|[4-9]\d|\d\d\d)' myfile
```